# Class for PDO vs Variable PDO

Tags: php, pdo

So currently I am using this for my PDO:

config.php

```
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname=driptone', MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);    

        try 
        {
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

And then I include it in every class that needs connection.

Usage:

```
$this->property = $pdo->prepare();
```

I've seen people doing this via a class, eg Class Database.
They are running it through a constructor, and I wanted to ask,

**What is exactly the difference between them? How do you actually create a database handling using PDO  , in it's own class?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **extend** PDO

```
class PDO_Class extends PDO {
   ...
}
```

Comment: And how do I use it? Sorry I just don't get it. But thanks!

Comment: @user2326532 I gave you an example right there...